# can you can in a instant pot pressure cooker? is so is there specifics

Tags: canning

I have an instant pot and would like to know if you can can in it and if so is there things you should NOT can in it. thank you  Tera

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot can in the Instant pot. They have been trying to bring out a new model which is also usable for canning, but last time I heard about it, they had trouble getting it to work for that. If you want to do pressure canning, you need an actual pressure canner.